# Android HttpPost request exception

Tags: android, json, request, http-post

Just as a demonstration the code will work, I am attempting to fetch some JSON data within my oncreate function. I know it should run on a different thread but I want to be sure the code successfully fetches my JSON before moving it into its own thread.

The code is below:

```
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        /***************************************************/
        final String TAG = "PostFetcher";
        final String SERVER_URL = "http://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts";
//        final String TAG = "PostsActivity";
//        List<Post> posts;

        try {
            //Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);

            //Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("M/d/yy hh:mm a");
                    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                    List<JsonObject> posts = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();

                    Log.e(TAG, "Checking: " + posts);

//                    posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject[].class));
                    content.close();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
        }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the second to last exception message:

```
Server responded with status code: 500
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error code 500 is Internal Server Error... server crashed..

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do you use `HttpPost`? That's the 4th or 5th time in the past 10 days I see people using `HttpPost` to read JSON from server via one kind or another of RESTful API

Comment: @Tseng: I am new to Android and Java coding and the code I got the code from a tutorial. It's only slightly modified by me

Comment: Does your problem still persists? If none of the answers solved your problem you may want to provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a `HttpPost` request to (obviously) an website that uses RESTful styled API.

This means, it works with HTTP Verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

If you want to read data and the read access never changes data, use GET.

If you want to update or replace data, user PUT or POST (put usually to replace, POST to change/add). However, JavaScript does (or did) only support GET and POST requests, so keep that in mind.

If you want to delete a resource or collection, use DELETE.

That being said: If you want to load data, use Get in your case `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost`.

Also read more about [RESTful web APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restful).

**Edit:**
In fact, calling the given URL in [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) (as stated in the comment on the other answer) results a HTML website reporting the error:

> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and
>   you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL
>   while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to
>   kylewbanks.com/rest/posts/ (note the trailing slash), or set
>   APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just wondered if you can tell me why the trailing slash? What significance does the slash hold?

Comment: That's some naming or url convention from Django. The quoted text is the error message that was returned from the webserver, when `http://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts` was called via Http Post request (you can't do that from browser, you need a tool like Fiddler to send post requests)

Comment: The reason I answered further before. GET request in RESTful APIs is used to read data so an url like `http://kylewbanks.com/rest/posts` will read all posts. When calling this via POST or PUT, it means you want to do something with the posts (i.e. delete all or multiple posts, replace them with another resource collection etc.). Read the Wiki link to get a better idea about RESTful API

Answer (score 0):

Its internal server error..check if there are any exceptions are getting thrown at server side.

It has nothing to do with your android code, the problem is at server.

You can use `AsyncTask` to run network/filesystem related operations.

Comment: That's not it. The URL works fine when copy & pasted in the browser. But if you use Fiddler2 to forge an POST request, you get 500 error. Because in RESTful API you can't read data with POST request, only write it. And since he didn't sent any parameters to update the data, it results in an error